# Zoo Flexible Admin + MSM Needs Hard Refresh - how to avoid?

Tags: javascript, control-panel, htaccess

This is based on this Support Thread:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-flexible-admin/viewthread/4202

In short: the menu in MSM doesn't change without HARD refreshes every time.

It looks like no one has managed to crack this nut yet and it's partially due to the ExpiresHeader, but I have no idea how to exclude a certain path by the expires header rule or any other way.

Thoughts? Client keeps emailing me saying she can't find things due to switching sites -- irony, since the Flexible Admin is meant to make it easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that you're running into an issue whereby your server sets content expiry headers for javascript and that's resulting in the addon's output being cached. I recently [submitted a bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19055) for this issue, with the proposed fix being to explicitly set a `no-cache` header for javascript generated via the `cp_js_end` hook. The fix has been accepted for a future release but who knows when that will be. In the meantime you can apply it manually:

Open up controllers/cp/javascript.php and locate the `_ext_scripts()` function. Within that function locate this line:

```
$this->output->set_header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

Immediately underneath it add this:

```
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

This will override your default headers and should ensure that a fresh copy of the `ext_scripts` output is retrieved with each page request.

Comment: If I do this, then I can keep my .htaccess as-is w/o commenting the Javascript line out?

Comment: You should be able to, yes. It's certainly worked for me and this patch will be included in the next EE release, so it's not as if you need to worry about this being a hack. You don't really want to stop sending those headers for other JS files as they will be static and you almost certainly do want them to be cached.

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear that sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

Is the ExpiresByType an htaccess rule you've added via HTML5 Boilerplate or something similar? I'd just comment it out. If it's from EE or an addon, try overriding it via an htaccess file that is closer to the files in question.

E.g., public_html/control_panel/.htaccess will be trump public_html/.htaccess

The files are cached by type so I don't think you can manually override a specific path.

Comment: OK, to double check, there's only ways to INCLUDE the ExpiresType not exclude 1 folder? That means, if I want the ExpiresHeaders on Javascript files, I would have to add a .htaccess file to specific/all Javascript folders EXCEPT the folder it's not supposed to expire?